# How to resolve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DerbyLogSetting

Tags: java, derby

I am dealing with derby to perform database related functions in a Java Project. The java project is a command line project. To accomplish this, I have added derby.jar into **libs** folder of my project, though on running application into netbeans, I am getting this error :

```
Mon Aug 18 17:32:23 IST 2014 Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DerbyLogSetting
----------------------------------------------------------------
Mon Aug 18 17:32:23 IST 2014:
Booting Derby version The Apache Software Foundation - Apache Derby - 10.8.1.2 - (1095077): instance a816c00e-0147-e8ff-2d32-000003436058 
on database directory My_Database_Path\Database_Path  with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@430e468f 
Loaded from file:/My_Project_Path/derby.jar
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.runtime.version=1.7.0_45-b18
user.dir=My_Project_Path
derby.system.home=null
derby.stream.error.method=DerbyLogSetting.disableDerbyLogFile
Database Class Loader started - derby.database.classpath=''
```

Same happening when I am running the exe of my project on command prompt. On goggling about the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11542719/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-netbeans-java-derby), I got that on adding derby-client into class path can solve my problem, but adding this jar (derbyclient-10.8.1.2.jar) into **libs** of my project not solving the issue.

What else needed to solve the issue ?

Comment: are you sure the jar is inside your build path ?

Comment: Yes, I have added derbyclient-10.8.1.2.jar into libs of my project.

Comment: How exactly are you running this application? For command prompt mentioned, can you post the full command being run.

Comment: For now, I am running the application using using Netbeans by passing the arguments (-arg1:val1 -arg2:val2) that are required to run my project. And same code when built to create exe, then it run using : MyProj.exe -arg1:val1 -arg2:val2 on command prompt.

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Have you added this derbyclient-10.8.1.2.jar in derby's lib folder.?

Comment: Same like including other Jars into a Java Project using Netbeans.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a classpath setting problem. You could add parameter -classpath your.jar when running using command line. Also incase running from IDE, you can specify the classpath in your run configurations.

Comment: Yes you have to show your classpath for your project here.

Comment: Classpath here : 
http://neelam.sharma.s3.amazonaws.com/DerbyClientAdded.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAINHDRCMKC5GUSNFA&Expires=1412015381&Signature=HxOKYPHJMD%2BufZH0AsH6Go6gvuE%3D